# How to calculate average of a column based on the distinct count of another column in SQL Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to have sum of the the total column be divided by the distinct count of each bill cycle.

I have tried this one below with no success, but this is what can come up from so far.

```sql
SELECT
    "Bill_TYPE",
    "BILL_CYCLE",
    "NET_TOTAL",
    SUM(
        SUM(
           CASE WHEN "BLI_TYPE" = 'Total Due'
           THEN "TABLE1"."MTD_TOT"
           ELSE 0 END)
         ) / (1* count(distinct(BILL_CYCLE)
     ) OVER() AS X,
FROM 
   "TABLE1"    
WHERE 
   ("TABLE1"."BILL_CYCLE"  
     BETWEEN :START_DATE AND :END_DATE )    
GROUP BY 
   "BILL_TYPE", "BILL_CYCLE", "NET_TOTAL"
```

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT
    "Bill_TYPE",
    "BILL_CYCLE",
    "NET_TOTAL",
    (SUM(
        SUM(
           CASE WHEN "BLI_TYPE" = 'Total Due'
           THEN "TABLE1"."MTD_TOT"
           ELSE 0 END)
         )) OVER())/1*count(distinct(BILL_CYCLE)) AS X,
FROM 
   "TABLE1"    
WHERE 
   ("TABLE1"."BILL_CYCLE"  
     BETWEEN :START_DATE AND :END_DATE )    
GROUP BY 
  "BILL_TYPE", "BILL_CYCLE", "NET_TOTAL"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).